# Another question about icons and push notifications

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, backendless

I searched a lot for this question in these last days and any answer that I saw until now it couldn't help.

I'm developing an app with React-Native and after trying with a lot of modules to send push notifications, I decided to use the services of Backendless.

Their system works very fine but I can't find an answer to what or where change to show a custom icon instead of the default white square in the notification.

I inserted the meta-data firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon in AndroidManifest.xml, I tried to make modifications in the function that set icon inside of the backendless module, tried to use Android vector drawable instead of png and some others things, everything I tried not worked.

Has someone any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [Backendless support topic:](https://support.backendless.com/t/another-topic-about-icons/10815/8?u=maksym_khobotin)

To set a custom icon for the Android push notification please follow the next steps:

1. Locate your icon in the drawable or mipmap directory of your Android project.
2. Create the push template from the Console and set the value of “Small Icon” field to the name of your icon (but without file extension).
3. Save the template and send the notification from Console or with API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LFanT! It can be usefuI for others persons that deal with the same issue in the future and can find the answer here in Stack Overflow. I was the one that opened this linked topic too. It was because I was not expectating to be answered by there, that was the reason I did the question here too.

Comment: The support forum is a preferred way to report the problem but we also monitor other sites. Glad you resolved your issue! @RobérioMatos

Comment: @LFTan Unfortunately the related issue hasn't solved. I would like to use the Backendless services because I liked what they offer and their prices schemes, but maybe it will be necessary to look for others services again.